# \\x96 is not a valid UTF-8 string in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We're seeing BigQuery produce invalid utf-8 errors when the " - " (dash) character is used in pipe delimited csv files. The weird thing is, these characters are in files that are over a year old, have not changed, and BigQuery has been reading the files for many months just fine until a few days ago. Here's an example of one of the errors.

```
Christus Trinity Clinic \\x96 Rheumatology is not a valid UTF-8 string
```

The way the string looks in the original file is like this:

```
Christus Trinity Clinic – Rheumatology
```

Does anyone know the fix for this or if BigQuery has changed it's functionality in a way that might cause this issue? I know that I can just upload a corrected file, but in this scenario the files are not supposed to change for auditing purposes.

Comment: How are you uploading these files to BQ? Directly from GCS? Host using Python client? Apache Beam?

Comment: These files are being stored in Google Storage and read by BigQuery there as an external table.

Comment: If this looks like a bug, please share job ids and file locations on the bigquery issue tracker. Especially if these files have not been changed, but the behavior has.

Comment: We are facing exactly the same issues since  tuesday 13 august. Clearly seems like a change of behavior of bq load csv files

Comment: I've opened a new issue item for this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139511264

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue from aug 14.
I am using `gsutil` to load the csv into bigquery.

I had used the encoding option while loading the csv and it is working for me.

**Encoding:**

`--encoding ISO-8859-1`

**Command line:**

```
bq --location=US load --skip_leading_rows=1 --encoding ISO-8859-1 --replace --source_format=CSV gcs.dim_employee
```

Answer (score 0):

We saw the same thing suddenly happen since yesterday.
For me, the solution was to add a encoding type to the loadconfig.
(I'm using the PHP client, but your client probably also has this option)

`$loadConfig->encoding('ISO-8859-1');`

Comment: FYI, if you are on the google cloud slack, I opened a conversation about this [here](https://googlecloud-community.slack.com/archives/C0E2CFHJT/p1565943161133800). So far one user also came forward with the same issue.